# If I have four groups of 100 items, is there a way in R to randomly select ten of them that make the most uniform distribution on some variable?

Tags: r, distribution, sample, sampling

Lets say that I have four groups, each of 100 items. They each have a rating on variable X.

I would like to randomly select ten from each group, with the caveat that the ten should evenly span variable X.

In other words, I would like the ten I draw from each group to have the most uniform distribution on variable X possible.

I've tried using cut points and `stratified()` but this hasn't worked because the different groups have somewhat different distributions. I've also tried using quantiles, but this has led to normal rather than uniform distributions.

Thanks!

here is some sample data

```
item = 1:400
group = rep(1:4, each = 100)
x = rnorm(400)

d <- as.data.frame(cbind(item,group,x))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use rank order statistics (I inreased the population size so that you can visually see it work):

```
#Prep data
item = 1:4000
group = rep(1:4, each = 1000)
x = rnorm(4000)   
d <- as.data.frame(cbind(item,group,x))

#Load package (need purrr installed as well)
library(dplyr)
#Draw the sample
sample_size <- 10
drawn_sample <- d %>% 
  mutate(
    rank = rank(x)
  ) %>% 
  split.data.frame(.$group) %>% 
  purrr::map(
    filter,
    rank %in% sample(rank, sample_size)
  ) %>% 
  bind_rows()
#Visualize sample vs original distribution    
x %>% 
  density() %>% 
  plot()
drawn_sample$x %>% 
  density() %>% 
  lines(col = 'red')
```